# nodejs request module returning ECONNREFUSED on localhost

Tags: node.js, request, node-modules, nodejs-server

I am trying to make an api call to my localhost but I always get
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5005 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)`

```
var url = `http://127.0.0.1:5005/api/entities/myEndpoint?id=121`;
var options = {
      url: url
    };
request.get(options, function(err, response, body) {
  console.log(err, response,body);
});
```

It does work if I use an IP instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

Check if your server has bound the port to its external IP only. On Linux, check `netstat -tulpen | grep 5005`. The output will contain the Server's listener address, e.g. `0.0.0.0:5005` or `::5005` both means that the server listens on all Interfaces for port `5005`.

If your result is something like `<ip address>:5005` where `ip address` is different from `127.0.0.1` that means that the server listens on that ip and port combination only and cannot be accessed using `localhost`, even if you are logged into the server.